# Typing groups in geometry

Tags: amsmath

I have already searched for a rigorous answer to this question, but ended up with aesthetic opinions only. I hope someone can help.

I am writing a document about geometry, and some specific groups crop up here and there. I have seen that groups like the orthogonal and unitary ones are generally written using `\mathrm` (cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) under the voice 'Properties'). On the other hand, it looks like the 1-sphere or the cross product of 1-spheres are not typed this way (cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)).

Is there any general rule about typing such groups? or does this depend only on the aesthetic taste of the writer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What is the specific question about latex?

Comment: I am unsure about how to type some specific groups. As an example, I do not know whether $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ is formally more correct than $SU(n)$.

Comment: Probably any answer will be opinion-based, but I personally would strongly prefer $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ over $SU(n)$ because the latter may be confused with the product of two matrices $S$ and $U(n)$. The Lie algebras can be nicely typeset with $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ and the like, and then its perhaps advantageous to denote their complex extensions as $\mathrm{A}_{n-1}$, $\mathrm{G}_2$, $\mathrm{E}_8$ etc. to have something that looks different from the $(n-1)$ row of the Cartan matrix etc. Finally, some like to denote the $n$-sphere as $\mathbbm{S}^n$ (or  $\mathbb{S}^n$).

Comment: This is a question of personal style, but in any case note the subtle difference between `SU(n)` and `\mathit{SU}(n)`